# Azure App Configuration trace request ip address?

Tags: azure, trace, appsettings, azure-app-configuration

I have multiple web apps retrieving the app settings from Azure App Configuration Service on startup without any refresh options.  I also have eventgrid and webhooks set up to push notifications of key changes down from the Azure App Configuration service to each web app. Everything is working and I should not get that many incoming http request to the Azure App Configuration service. But sometimes I'm getting unexpecting httprequests in the Azure App Configuration metrics. I can't seem to find any other information about each request to figure out which app may not be configured correctly. Is there a log or appinsights that captures more information for each request made to the Azure App Configuration Service?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on exposing request logs to your App Configuration store. The information of client IP addresses will be included. The feature is tracked in https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/333. It should be available soon.